# Commutative and Associative Properties for Addition

Tags: arithmetic

I am trying to find out the difference between Commutative and Associative Properties for Addition. I got this from a elementary school kid, sadly I was unable to answer his question.

basically his question is,

What is the addition property for ?

```
23+42+59 -- Answer is Associative

12+92+98+65 -- Answer is Commutative
```

My question is, how they categorize  23+42+59 as Associative and 12+92+98+65 as Commutative.

Because, in case of 23+42+59, we  also switch (number commute) numbers and get the same answer. Is that case it can also be Commutative

and  in case of 12+92+98+65, we also associate numbers and get the same answer. Is that case it can also be Associative.

help me understand.

Comment: Do you think you heard it wrong? Maybe instead of 23+42+59 it was 23+(42+59)? I can't think of one for the commutative tho.